# Keeping data structure views consistent

Tags: java, data-structures, synchronization

I have a `Map` of `Order`s that can be accessed by many different threads. I want to control access, so consider the following simple data structure + wrapper.

```
public interface OrderContainer {
    boolean contains(String orderId);
    Order get(String orderId);
    Order register(Order value);
    Order remove(String orderId);
    Collection<Order> getOrders();
}

public class SimpleOrderContainer implements OrderContainer {
    private Map<String, Order> orders = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private Collection<Order> ordersView = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(orders.values());

    @Override
    public boolean contains(String orderId) {
        return orders.containsKey(orderId);
    }

    @Override
    public Order get(String orderId) {
        return orders.get(orderId);
    }

    @Override
    public Order register(Order value) {
        return orders.put(value.getId(), value);
    }

    @Override
    public Order remove(String orderId) {
        return orders.remove(orderId);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Collection<Order> getOrders() {
        return ordersView;
    }
}
```

Very easy. Now, `Order` has another method, `getType`. I want to [decorate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) my class to be able to access `Order`s by type, but I don't want to have to iterate over the whole map every time I call this method; I want to keep a view that has this information.

#### The problems:

1. Keeping the two views consistent with each other in a threadsafe way
2. Possible over-synchronization in my attempt to do #1, affecting performance
3. I can't ensure no one keeps a reference to the original `OrderContainer`, which would allow my `typeView` to be out of sync.

Here's my first attempt at the decorated class. This attempt almost certainly over-synchronizes:

```
public class TypeOrderContainer implements OrderContainer {
    private OrderContainer backing;
    
    private Map<String, Map<String, Order>> typeView = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    TypeOrderContainer(OrderContainer backing) {
        this.backing = backing;
    }

    public boolean contains(String orderId) {
        return backing.contains(orderId);
    }

    public Order get(String orderId) {
        return backing.get(orderId);
    }

    public synchronized Order register(Order value) {
        String type = value.getType();
        
        Map<String, Order> innerMap = getInnerMap(type);
        innerMap.put(value.getId(), value);
        
        return backing.register(value);
    }

    private Map<String, Order> getInnerMap(String type) {
        if(!typeView.containsKey(type)) {
            return addInnerMap(type);
        } else {
            return typeView.get(type);
        }
    }

    private Map<String, Order> addInnerMap(String type) {
        Map<String, Order> innerMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        
        typeView.put(type, innerMap);
        
        return innerMap;
    }

    public synchronized Order remove(String orderId) {
        Order order = backing.remove(orderId);
        
        if(order == null) return null;
        
        String type = order.getType();
        Map<String, Order> innerMap = getInnerMap(type);
        if(innerMap == null) {
            // I suspect this is not the best error handling logic
            throw new IllegalStateException("Somehow the inner map is out of sync!!");
        } else {
            innerMap.remove(order.getId());
            // Could do this if you want, likely not necessary in my use case
            // if (innerMap.isEmpty()) typeView.removeInnerMap(); 
        }
        
        return order;
    }

    public Collection<Order> getOrders() {
        return backing.getOrders();
    }
    
    public Map<String, Order> getOrdersByType(String type) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(getInnerMap(type));
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to keep the views of my data consistent and still threadsafe?

Comment: So, the concern is that the callers of `getOrders()` will do something nefarious to the the data?  Would deep cloning help?  This way, callers would only be operating on the cloned collection, not the original.  Deep cloning could be rather expensive, though

Comment: @CodeChimp `getOrders` is safe because it's wrapped in an `unmodifiableList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe #3 is possible in your case.  Essentially what you want is that when an insert/delete happens in the `OrderContainer` (without using your `TypeOrderContainer` decorator), you want `TypeOrderContainer` (specifically your typeView) to know about the inserts/deletes at the same time (see how there's already a backwards dependency there?).  If this is not what you asked, ignore the rest of this answer.

In your case, you have a completely separate view of the referenced `OrderContainer` in which a relation between `String type` and `Collection<Order> typedOrders` is being built and maintained.  By the methods declared in the `OrderContainer`, we can at best assume that there is `Collection<Order> allOrders`.  Now let's imagine there's `typeOrders1` and `typeOrders2` and together, they form `allOrders`.  If I insert an Order into `allOrders`, how would the collection of `allOrders` know which `typeOrder` to put the new Order in? The answer is that `allOrders` won't unless it understands the relationship of type --> Orders, and if it does, it destroys the point of this decorator.  Ultimately, it's not possible to have subsets understand updates to the original set unless the subsets understand a range it's looking for, and your allOrders doesn't have a "type" range.  If you're interested, java's [TreeSet.subSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) has a very similar problem, in which any additions outside the range of the specified subSet will not show up.

On the other hand, I believe your solution is already designed well for your purposes.  One optimization I would make is to reduce the synchronization.  The only time you need typeView to be synchronized is when you're inserting a brand new type:

```
// This assumes your maps are ConcurrentHashMaps
public Order register(Order value) { // No synchronized here since CHM does it for you
    Map<String, Order> innerMap = getInnerMap(type);
    innerMap.put(value.getId(), value);

    return backing.register(value);
}

private Map<String, Order> getInnerMap(String type) {
    if (!typeView.containsKey(type)) {
        synchronized(typeView)  {
            if (!typeView.containsKey(type)) { // make sure no one else snuck in after you "checked"
                typeView.put(type, new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
            }
        }
    }
    return typeView.get(type);
}

public Order remove(String orderId) { // No synchronized here since CHM does it for you
    Order order = backing.remove(orderId);

    if(order == null) return null;

    String type = order.getType();
    Map<String, Order> innerMap = getInnerMap(type);
    if(innerMap == null) {
        // I suspect this is not the best error handling logic
        throw new IllegalStateException("Somehow the inner map is out of sync!!");
    } else {
        innerMap.remove(order.getId());
        // Could do this if you want, likely not necessary in my use case
        // if (innerMap.isEmpty()) typeView.removeInnerMap(); 
    }

    return order;
}

public Collection<Order> getOrders() {
    return backing.getOrders();
}

public Map<String, Order> getOrdersByType(String type) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(getInnerMap(type));
}
```

Also, a [typical decorator pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern-gui-example-java-sourcecode.html) example will show that this is normally possible because a decorator class simply wraps around the backed object (in your case `OrderContainer backing`) and overridden methods apply **additions** to the backed object.  However, since you're basically translating (/breaking apart) the OrderContainer to another view, this doesn't quite work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to sift the original map for every call, why not keeping another map of type to orders and everytime you change the original map you update the type map synchronized accordingly? Further thinking, I would certainly question if it is more complex to synchronize two collections then to iterate a collection and build copy "on the fly".

Comment: Smutje, your first sentence is exactly what the included solution does.

Comment: Yes, but you somehow keep a (duplicate?) backing collection.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, it's just a [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)